# Wordpress development - local and remote paths

Tags: wordpress, relative-path

I'm trying to set up wordpress so that relative paths work on both my localhost development and my live site.

I was hoping it was just a matter of changing the "site" URL and "home" URL to `http://localhost/` and `www.example.com`, and then links would be relative. However this is not the case, and I think `.htaccess` complicates the issue.

Eg, if I want to access a file in www.example.com/wp-content/mydirectory I can do this:

```
$url = '/wp-content/mydirectory/myfile.php'
```

but on my local site I have to do this:

```
$url= '/www.example.com/wp-content/mydirectory/myfile.php'
```

I have a solution by conditionally echoing a var at the start of the path, but it's not always possible to use PHP to accomplish this, for example, in a post or page where the link is in the content.

Does anyone have an elegant solution?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the database and look inside the config table. There's a value for home (and possibly another value called URL, the table is not too big, so give it a quick scan), change that to your local environment for testing and when you're ready, you can change the record in the database and upload to your remote server.

Comment: Hmm.. that what I meant in para 2 by changing 'home' and 'site' urls.

Comment: Well, that's what I always do and it definitely works for me. I don't use .htaccess on my local either.